# Greedy algorithm for active contours - shrinking

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I am studying and implementing the Greedy algorithm for active contours as described in paper by Donna Williams - A Fast Algorithm For Active Contours And Curvature Estimation.

One of the advantages over another implementation (by Kass et al.) should be uniform distribution of points along the contour curve. In every iteration each point tries to move itself so the distance to the previous point is as close to the average as possible.

The contour is expected to be drawn around an object in image and then to shrink around it until it is "attached" to the object edges.

But the problem is that the contour won't shrink. It evolves so that the points are equally spaced to each other along the contour, but the contour cannot shrink around the image object because distances between points would go below average and the algorithm would move them back.

Do you have any thoughts on this? What am I missing? Other implementations of active contours do shrink, but have another drawbacks and the Greedy algorithm is supposed to be better and more stable.

Answer (score 0):

The researchers hardly emphasize the disadvantages of their new solution.
Dont trust the paper, too much, If you don't have heard from other sources, that
this algorithm works.
I would implement only an algorithm if it is well accepted in literature (or if I have invented it ;-) ).
Companies need a robust solution that works, a researcher must publish something new,
which may be less useable in practise, and sometimes only works well on specific test sets.